# Javascript default in Rails 3.0

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

In the file `application.html.erb`, I see the line

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

What does `:defaults` mean here? What Javascript files does it include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To include the Prototype and Scriptaculous javascript libraries in
>   your application, pass `:defaults` as the source. When using `:defaults`,
>   if an application.js file exists in your public javascripts directory,
>   it will be included as well.

[Source](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag)

In other words:

- prototype.js
- controls.js
- dragdrop.js
- effects.js
- rails.js (this one is not listed in the API, but it *is* included)
- application.js if it exists

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3.0, the `:defaults` options **includes Prototype.js/Scriptaculous and your application.js**, though it's a slight bit more nuanced than that. In Rails 3.2, **jQuery** is loaded instead. Here's an excerpt from the current `javascript_include_tag` documentation:

> If the application is not using the asset pipeline, to include the default JavaScript expansion pass :defaults as source. By default, :defaults loads jQuery, and that can be overridden in config/application.rb:
>
> ```
> config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(foo.js bar.js)
> ```
>
> When using :defaults, if an application.js file exists in public/javascripts it will be included as well at the end.

The [Layout and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) guide has a section titled [Linking to JavaScript files with the `javascript_include_tag`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#linking-to-javascript-files-with-the-javascript_include_tag) that covers this behavior as well.